# How Do I Stop jUnit From Pulling Time Zone Data from My PC Into Test?

Tags: java, junit

I have a series of test that are currently failing for a project that was previously being worked on the west coast. I am in central time, and the test were hard coded with a date and time in PDT. It is for at team that is in separate time zones, so I can't just hard code CDT. What options do I have so that jUnit will stop pulling my time zone from my system?

Comment: What do you mean by "pulls time zone"? Is it used somewhere in tests? Why is it a problem?

Comment: I have multiple test failing because "test was expecting PST and got CST"

Comment: It's getting CST, because I am in CST, so for some reason even though the test is something like assertEquals("6/15/2013 11:15:41 PST", 

It is pulling my time zone in.

Comment: Ok, so assertions are not as clever as they could be. What kinds of assertions are these? Where it expects to find `PST`? In LocalDateTimes?

Comment: How do you run the unit test? You can set the environment timezone by specifying the `export TZ=Europe/Paris`, for example, in your bash script.

Comment: It's a java Junit test in Eclipse.

Comment: Or maybe it's worth to convert the dates to proper time zone before assertions. Or maybe it's worth to assert with actual DateTime objects, not with `String`s.

Comment: We need to see your test code. There are a number of ways of dealing with time zones, but we need code to make suggestions.

Comment: It is with String, so that's probably a solid suggestion. It's from the older team, so I'm going to try that.

Comment: As said earlier, you can set `TZ` environment in Eclipse when running the test.

Answer (score 2):

You need to refactor the code. I assume, you have hardcoded ZonedDateTime.now() or something similar somewhere in your code. Say

```
public void method() {
    method1(ZonedDateTime.now());
}
```

So, it's impossible to control to pass your own value, to inject it. Should become:

```
public void method(ZonedDateTime zdt) {
    method1(zdt);
}
```

Now the code becomes testable and you can pass any value you want, for example you can parse a string with whatever time zone you need as a zoned date time.

Comment: The problem is the hardcoded date is something back in 2012 or 2013. So for example, I can pull the timezone off my system, but that I realized doesn't matter, because it's the time itself that is the issue.

the code that's causing the issue is something like ("6/15/2013 11:15:41 PST") and then some proprietary methods. 

So when the test fails even with the Time Zone update it now fails because it expected 9: 41 and got 11:41 because